# Is there any neat way to show $\phi$ is a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

In Michael Artin's *Algebra* (chapter 2, page 50, example 2.5.13) the author illustrates a homomorphism from $S_4$ (all permutations of indices $(1,2,3,4)$) to $S_3$ (all permutations of indices $(1,2,3)$), as is shown in the picture below:
[image]

I understand how the map sends an element from $S_4$ into $S_3$, but I just don't understand why this is a homomorphism. The author remarks that

> If $p,q$ are elements of $S_4$, the product $pq$ is the composed permutation $p\circ q$, and the action of $pq$ on the set $\{\Pi_1,\Pi_2,\Pi_3\}$ is the composition of the actions of $q$ and $p$. Therefore $\phi(pq)=\phi(p)\phi(q)$.

But it isn't clear to me how $\phi(p),\phi(q)$ can be so "composed"... It might not be hard to imagine, but how to sketch a *rigorous* proof?

Of course there are finite cases so we can always do it case by case, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: not sure if this is relevant to you, but if you just want to find a homomorphism you can just map elements in $S_4$ to their respective elements in $S_3$ but "truncate" any $4$. Then it is clearly a homomorphism.

Comment: @ElliotG though it is not relevant, it's still interesting.  How to "truncate" 4? Do you mean in the cycle notation?

Comment: Sorry I should clarify you would use permutations which fix 4. So (132) for example would map to (132) in $S_3$. You couldn't so easily do that for every element of $S_4$, just the subgroup which fixes 4.

Comment: @ElliotG But then you do not get a homomorphism on all of $S_4$... only those elements in the subgroup that fixes 4.

Comment: Yeah you're right. You would have a homomirphism $S_3$ to $S_4$ but that doesn't help with your problem

Comment: A permutation $\rho$ of a set $S$ induces a permutation $\rho'$ on the power set ${\mathcal P}(S)$ by setting $\rho'(T) := \{\rho(t)\mid t\in T\}$ for $T\subseteq S$. Which permutation does the inverse $\rho^{-1}$ of $\rho$ induce on ${\mathcal P}(S)$? Which permutation does the product $\rho\circ\sigma$ induce on ${\mathcal P}(S)$ if $\sigma$ is another permutation of $S$?

Comment: @j.p. This seems to be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Vim: If you were able to answer my second question, then you know that $':Sym(S)\to Sym({\mathcal P}(S)), \rho \mapsto \rho'$ is a group homomorphism. You should be able to check that all $\rho'$ preserve cardinality (i.e., $|T| = |\rho'(T)|$ for all $T\subseteq S$) and disjointness (i.e., $T\cap U=\emptyset$ implies $\rho'(T)\cap \rho'(U)=\emptyset$ for all $T, U\subseteq S$).

Comment: @j.p. Yes indeed! these results are useful. Maybe now I should be able to check that $$' : \text{Sym}(\{1,2,3,4\})\to\text{Sym}(\mathcal P_2(\{1,2,3,4\}))$$ is a homomorphism in a similar manner? ($\mathcal P_2$ denotes all the subsets that contain two elements).

Comment: @j.p. However the range seems to be an $S_6$... isn't it? Then how to reconstruct this $S_4\to S_3$ homomorphism?

Comment: @Vim: If you like it abstract, you can use $':Sym(\mathcal{P}(S))\to Sym(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(S)))$ and look what $\rho''(\{\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}\})$ is.

Comment: @Vim: Or you could use $S\setminus \rho'(T) = \rho'(S\setminus T)$ somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any element of $S_4$ sends any partition of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to a similar partition of $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

For example, any $\sigma \in S_4$ sends a $3+1$ partition of $4$ to a $3+1$ partition of $4$: if $\sigma = (1\ 3\ 4)$, for example, $\sigma$ sends the $3+1$ partition $\{\{3\},\{1,2,4\}\}$ to the partition: $\{\{\sigma(3)\},\{\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\sigma(4)\}\}= \{\{4\},\{1,2,3\}\}$.

Since the mappings in $S_4$ are *bijective*, we induce a bijective map on the set of all partitions of any given type, that is: an *action* on the set $P$ of these partition-types, which is by defintion a homomorphism $S_4 \to P$.

The possible partition-types of $4$ are these:

$4$ = $\{\{a,b,c,d\}\}$-there are only one of these, and this induces the trivial homomorphism $S_4 \to S_1$.

$3+1 = \{\{a\},\{b,c,d\}\}$-there are $4$ of these and this induces an isomorphism $S_4 \to S_4$.

$2+2 = \{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}$-there are $3$ of these, and this induces a homomorphism $S_4 \to S_3$.

$2+1+1 = \{\{a,b\},\{c\},\{d\}\}$-there are $6$ of these and this induces a homomorphism $S_4 \to S_6$.

$1+1+1+1 = \{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{d\}\}$-there is just one of these, and it also induces the trivial homomorphism.

A similar technique to this, is used to find outer automorphisms of $S_6$.

EDIT: I was going to add this, this morning, but was rushed for time. It's clear we have an *action* on $S_3$ by letting $S_4$ induce an action on the set of $2+2$ partitions of $\{1,2,3,4\}$, but all this guarantees is we have a homomorphism *into* $S_3$. Let's see that this homomorphism is indeed surjective.

Denote $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\} = a, \{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\} = b, \{\{1,4\},\{2,3\}\} = c$.

Let's examine the mapping of $\{a,b,c\}$ to itself induced by $\sigma = (1\ 2)$.

Clearly, $(1\ 2)$ sends $a \to a$, and $b$ gets sent to:

$\{\{\sigma(1),\sigma(3)\},\{\sigma(2),\sigma(4)\}\} = \{\{2,3\},\{1,4\}\} = c.$

Similarly, $(1\ 2)$ sends $c$ to:

$\{\{\sigma(1),\sigma(4)\},\{\sigma(2),\sigma(3)\}\} = \{\{2,4\},\{1,3\}\} = b$.

Thus $(1\ 2)$ induces the $2$-cycle $(b\ c)$.

One can verify in the same way that $(2\ 3)$ induces the $2$-cycle $(a\ b)$.

Since $S_3$ is generated by any $2$ distinct transpositions, this shows our homomorphism is onto.

Order (via Lagrange and the fundamental isomorphism theorem) arguments show the kernel has order $24/6 = 4$.

One can verify directly that:

$\tau = (1\ 2)(3\ 4)$ acting on $\{a,b,c\}$ clearly sends $a \to a$, and sends:

$b \to \{\{\tau(1),\tau(3)\},\{\tau(2),\tau(4)\}\} = \{\{2,4\},\{1,3\}\} = b$

(sets don't care which order their elements are listed in).

Thus $\tau$ *must* send $c \to c$, that is, $\tau$ induces the identity map on $\{a,b,c\}$-so $\tau$ is in the kernel of our homomorphism.

Since the kernel (being a kernel) is a normal subgroup of $S_4$, it thus contains all *conjugates* of $\tau$, that is, all $2,2$-cycles (of which there are $3$). The identity map "fills it up", we have $4$ elements, and can have no more (although you can verify in the same manner that the other $2,2$-cycles also induce the identity map on $\{a,b,c\}$.

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling to see the subjectivity till you made this edit, really great help!  Just a minor question if u don't mind, you said that $\tau$ is in the kernel and so are all its conjugates, that is, *all* 2,2-cycles. Is it very natural that each 2,2-cycle is indeed a conjugate of $\tau$? (Well I know it's easy to just verify, but I'm just wondering if I'm missing some point here so that I can't see this very immediately. )

Comment: Yes, all cycle-types of the same type are conjugate. This is a consequence of $\sigma(a_1\ a_2\ \dots\ a_k)\sigma^{-1}$ being equal to the $k$-cycle $(\sigma(a_1)\ \sigma(a_2)\ \dots\ \sigma(a_k))$.

Comment: nicely  explained. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that there are exactly $3$ possible pairings of $4$ objects. Every permutation of the $4$ objects will correspond to mapping one pairing to another, and so is essentially a permutation of the pairings. Composition of permutations will then also correspond to the composition of the corresponding mappings, and so it is a homomorphism from $S_4$ to $S_3$.

Comment: "Composition of permutations will then also correspond to the composition of the corresponding mappings". But this is not clear. After all, what I want to know is exactly *how* the correspondence happens, i.e., how $\phi(p)\phi(q)$ is determined by $p\circ q$ **in the same way** as $\phi(p)$ is determined by $p$ and $\phi(q)$ is determined by $q$.

Answer (score 1):

Any permutation $\pi\in{\cal S}_4\bigl([4]\bigr)$ acts on the *elements* of $[4]$, and there is no simple formula describing the resulting action of $\pi$ on the set $P$ of *pairings* of $[4]$. Therefore I shall realize the pairings as edge colorings of the complete graph $K_4$ on the vertex set $[4]$,  as follows:

Identifying an element of $P$, i.e., a pairing of $[4]$, is the same as coloring two disjoint edges of $K_4$ red. Denote the set of possible such colorings by $P'$. Given any permutation $\pi:\>[4]\to[4]$, this permutation will automatically induce a permutation $\phi_\pi\in{\cal S}_3(P')$, and it is then obvious that 
$$\iota:\quad {\cal S}_4\bigl([4]\bigr)\to{\cal S}_3(P'),\qquad \pi\to\phi_\pi$$
is a homomorphism. The question whether $\iota$ is surjective has not been addressed.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know what is a $K_4$ and how many edges it has... Could you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

$S_n$ is generated by $q=(1 2)$ and $p=(1 2\cdots n)$. In other words, every element can be written as a string of these two. Thus you only need check the two-and threefold compositions of these elements satisfy the equation you name:

$\phi(p^3)=\phi(p)^3$

$\phi(p^2q)=\phi(p^2)\phi(q)$

$\phi(qp^2)=\phi(q)\phi(p^2)$

$\phi(p^2)=\phi(p)^2$

$\phi(pq)=\phi(p)\phi(q)$

$\phi(qp)=\phi(q)\phi(p)$.

Since any cycle in $S_n$ can be written (non-uniquely) as a word in $p$ and $q$, the result will follow from induction on the length of the word and the above. Note that if a cycle can be written as a word in $p$ and $q$ with an even number of letters, we only need refer to the last three equations.

Comment: I don't think this is true: For example, if we label the corners of a square by $1, 2, 3, 4$, the transposition $(13)$ and the $4$-cycle $(1234)$ in $S_4$ are both symmetries of the square. Hence the subgroup they generate is a subgroup of $D_8$, and in particular is not all of $S_4$. (In fact, they respectively act by a reflection and a rotation that generates the rotational subgroup, and so $\langle(13), (1234)\rangle \cong D_8$.) We can easily patch the solution, though, as e.g., $(12)$ and $(1 \cdots n)$ together *do* generate $S_n$.

Comment: Ah, yes, I meant that! Is transposition not the accepted term for cycles like $(1 2)$ but not like $(1 3)$? If not, is there one?

Comment: A transposition is just a swap, and does not specifically refer to a particular one. After all, what is the difference between object 2 and 3? Abstractly there is none.

Comment: @user21820 you misunderstand me: I want to know if there is a term used for cycles of the form $(k \;\;k+1)$.

Comment: No I didn't misunderstand you. I'm trying to give a vague explanation why there will not be such a term, because there is no canonical order of objects that would allow any such term to make sense.

Comment: So you'll have to explicitly write out both the cycle and the transposition that you wish to use, because both are dependent on each other. Note however that if you have a prime number of objects, you can prove that any transposition works.